# Accessing vm's external ip on GCP compute engine using ansible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

This is how I am trying to retrieve the external IP address of vms:

```
{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_env'].SSH_CONNECTION.split(' ')[2]}}
```

Here is another way to see all IP addresses associated with a node:
ansible  -m setup -i hosts -u

results:

```
ansible [hostname (or) hostgroup] -m setup -i hosts -u [user name] | grep SSH

"SSH_CLIENT": "<ip a> 57894 22",
"SSH_CONNECTION": "<ip a> 57894 <internal ip> 22",
"SSH_TTY": "/dev/pts/0",
```

What is getting returned using the first snippet is the 2nd IP i.e VM's internal IP.
How can ansible pull VM's external IP?
Also, what is IP a? It's certainly not the VM's external IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe 'ansible_host' variable would do the trick. The playbook below outputs the ip address of the vm.

```yaml
- name: Show vm's ip
  hosts: gcp
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ansible_host}}"
```

Comment: Yes. that is correct. Thanks.  I wonder why this variable was not there when I was running to see all the facts that ansible captured.   using (ansible [hostname (or) hostgroup] -m setup -i hosts -u [user name])